# lodepng, stb_image. Nothing works in my system for image loading in C++

Tags: c++, image, load, png, sdl

I'm trying to load pngs or bmps into my programs. But none of the libraries I found around the web works. I have no idea why but I always get "incorrect PNG signature, it's no PNG or corrupted" for EVERY png when using lodepng. "unknown pixel format" for EVERY bmp when using SDL_loadBMP. "unknown image type" for every png when using stb_image.

I can't load anything. Maybe there is something wrong with my system ? I'm using OSX Yosemite. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <lodepng.h>
#include <stb_image.h>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    string name = "res/img_test.png";
    const char * cstr = name.c_str();

    //lodepng
    unsigned char *buffer;
    unsigned int w,h;
    int result = lodepng_decode32_file(&buffer, &w, &h, cstr);
    cout << lodepng_error_text(result) << endl;

    //stb_image
    int x, y, comp;

    FILE *f = fopen(cstr, "rb");
    unsigned char *res;
    res = stbi_load_from_file(f,&x,&y,&comp,0);
    fclose(f);

    cout << stbi_failure_reason() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using latest cmake to build this with gcc. Any recommendatation is appreciated but consider this. I've tried many files (generated by me or grabbed from internet). Tested same files with other users of the these libraries. Their code worked and mine didn't.

Edit:

Here's the source with complete cmake project >> github.com/onatbas/png_load_test.git

Comment: Don't print error messages unless the functions you call actually fails. For example, what does `lodepng_decode32_file` or `stbi_load_from_file` return? Oh, and I assume that the file you're trying to load is an actual PNG image, that can be loaded from other programs?

Comment: They do return error values. For example lodepng returns 28 which stands for "corrupt png header". It is checking for png header and I traced it byte by byte. 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 . It looks like this. 5th 6th 7th bytes are wrong. But for every png????
The stb_image is also an error value. You can also say that becuase dimensions are 0 0 still. And the buffer is empty, when Ioad it into opengl texture2d , nothing is loaded, everything is black.
And for bmps (I tried with SDL2) I get this >> SDL_error "SDL Error: File is not a Windows BMP file"

Comment: If those bytes are at the start of your image, then it's definitely not a PNG image, whose header should start [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header).

Comment: Nope It is just a trace, if the bytes are as they should be. 5th, 6th and 7th bytes does not match. But like I said, for EVERY png. I tried the test files of these image libraries as well. I had some friends send me some pngs which are tested in their pc, and failed to load at my pc.

Comment: Have you transferred the files over the network using a protocol that does e.g. line-ending translations? Because if you look at the header I linked to in my previous comment, those bytes are there to detect those kind of problems. Have you looked at the first eight bytes in a hex-editor? Can you show them to us?

Comment: I added the project folder completely. Added it to git. Would you have a look at it, please?

Comment: Directly after the line declaring `cstr`, add a test to see if your code can see the file. Something simple such as attempting to `fopen` it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Thank you everyone for trying to help.
It wasn't a code issue, afterall. It is a configuration issue. My cmake script damages the pngs and bmps when trying to copy them into destination folder. The code is fine.